# saxon: using fn:doc() in a query parameter

Tags: xquery, saxon

Why can't I use fn:doc in a "query parameter using xpath"?

The document parameter is working fine:

```
saxon -q:test.xq +foo=foo.xml
```

But this gives me the error *"Unrecognized option: foo.xml"*

```
saxon -q:test.xq ?foo=doc("foo.xml")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably your shell. Different shells vary in their handling of special characters, but the quotes probably need escaping (with backslashes), or you could do

```
saxon -q:test.xq "?foo=doc('foo.xml')"
```